# Jquery sortable: Replace value text of input A by value of Input B if input A is in the first list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using Jquery sortable.

I have a first input call "Iwanttogetavalue" which is not in the two lists.

I have two lists draggable between eachothers.

Inputs are the items

Only one item (input) is draggable within the first list.

If a draggable input (item) (with a class named "giveavalue") is in the first list (sortable1), I want that the Input "Iwanttogetavalue" get the value from this input.

Here my code:

```
<input type="text" id="Iwanttogetavalue">

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedsortables">
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedsortables">
   <li><input type="text" class="giveavalue"></li>
   <li><input type="text" class="giveavalue"></li>
</ul>




<script>
$(function() {
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedsortables',
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).children().length > 1) {
            //ui.sender: will cancel the change.
            //Useful in the 'receive' callback.
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }
})
$("#sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedsortables',
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(this).children().length > 10) {
            //ui.sender: will cancel the change.
            //Useful in the 'receive' callback.
            $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
        }
    }
}).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

thank you !

Comment: Do you know what value inputA will be?

Comment: yes it will be manually written

Comment: Ok... I'll write a response accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to put this into the receive function so it's called every time you sort...

```
$('li .general_title').each(function () {
   var this_input = $(this);
   var id = this_input.attr('id');
   var value = this_input.val()
   if (id == "inputA") {
      $('#inputB').val(id);
   }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Actually, this is not working for me or I don't use it properly.

Comment: Brian Noah, Ive just edited my question which is I guess more understandable